# I don't know how to custom email template on PHPMaller?

Tags: php, mysql, mailer

I am using PHP Mailer for sending mail. It works perfectly sending plain email(default) but the mail should have some sort of HTML & CSS in it. so I would like to design a template on which the mail has to send. now it is not working for me and i don't know where to change or add a email template for mailing. Kindly give your ideas. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Just create a web page in HTML in a single file.

'HTML in single file part' means that where you would usually embed external CSS or JS files, now you have to write in the HTML file itself.

```
so, instead of:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">

you would use:
<style>
   # your css here
</style>
```

The HTML markup and the CSS itself should be very simple and light. Using few images if any is also advised, because in this case - the more images, the heavier the email will be.

After that just set the PHPMailer to HTML mode and include the page into the body.

Send an email to yourself and you will see how it looks like. Check the view in GMail, Outlook and other programs you think are more likely to be used by your target audience.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest tempmail.php class for setting templates to php mail. I used it recently. It works fine.

I give some example code here

```
include_once "class.tempmail.php";
$array_content[]=array("user_login", $email);  
$array_content[]=array("user_pass",  $password);
$array_content[]=array("user_name",  $username);
$phpmailer = "class.phpmailer.php";
mailsending::sendingemail_phpmailer($array_content, "/path-of-template-file/templatefilename", $phpmailer, "SENDER NAME","SENDER EMAIL","RECEIVER EMAIL","SUBJECT");
```

AND in template file, you can use variables like this.

```
<h2>Hi %%user_name%%</h2>
<p>Your login id is  %%user_login%%</p>
<p>Your password is %%user_pass%%</p>
```

You can download it from here.
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3088-PHP-Send-HTML-messages-using-templates.html#download